# How to import solutions in jupyter lab notebook

Tags: python

```
moduleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a733e16188a8> in <module>
      1 import os
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import time
      4 import numpy as np
```

how to resolve this problem i have installed anaconda software

Comment: by installing the module

Answer (score 0):

`cv2` Is [opencv](https://opencv.org/)

**Since you are using `conda` ([Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/))** you can install it using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` ([More here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv))

(or `!conda install -c conda-forge opencv` if you want to install it from within a Jupiter Notebook)

***(For others not using Anaconda)*** If you are not using Conda you should check the installation instructions for your operating system [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/da/df6/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_setup.html)